# Difference between #entries and #to_a in ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the basic difference between `#entries` and `#to_a` methods of `Enumerable` module in ruby.Both seem to return same result on a `Hash`

```
>> hash = {"name" => "foo" , "age" => "23"}
=> {"name"=>"foo", "age"=>"23"}

>> hash.to_a 
=> [["name","foo"],["age",23]]

>> hash.entries
=> [["name","foo"],["age",23]]
```

Comment: Ruby has both for the same reason it has `map` and `collect`: cosmetics/expressiveness.

Comment: @Denis I like your word *cosmetic* ... So *+1* ..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the difference(look at the output after `# =>`):

```
h = {}
h.method(:entries) # => #<Method: Hash(Enumerable)#entries>
h.method(:to_a) # => #<Method: Hash#to_a>
h.method(:entries).owner # => Enumerable
h.method(:to_a).owner # => Hash
```

`Hash` has an instance method [`#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_a), so it is not calling [`Enumerable#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a). But `Hash` doesn't has it's own method `#entries`, so it is calling [`Enumerable#entries`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries), because `Hash` included `Enumerable` module.

```
Hash.included_modules # => [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

There is no difference between `Enumerable#entries` and `Enumerable#to_a`, as far as I can see both are working similar way using [**TracePoint**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html):

```
1. trace = TracePoint.new do |tp|
2.    p [tp.lineno, tp.event, tp.defined_class,tp.method_id]
3. end
4.
5. trace.enable do
6.  (1..2).entries
7.  (1..2).to_a
8. end

# >> [5, :b_call, nil, nil]
# >> [6, :line, nil, nil]
# >> [6, :line, nil, nil]
# >> [6, :c_call, Enumerable, :entries]
# >> [6, :c_call, Range, :each]
# >> [6, :c_return, Range, :each]
# >> [6, :c_return, Enumerable, :entries]
# >> [7, :line, nil, nil]
# >> [7, :line, nil, nil]
# >> [7, :c_call, Enumerable, :to_a]
# >> [7, :c_call, Range, :each]
# >> [7, :c_return, Range, :each]
# >> [7, :c_return, Enumerable, :to_a]
# >> [8, :b_return, nil, nil]
```

Yes, `Hash#to_a` is faster than `Enumerable#to_a`.

**Part - I**

```
require 'benchmark'

class Hash
  remove_method :to_a
end

hsh = Hash[*1..1000]


Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report("Enumerable#to_a")    { hsh.to_a }
end
# >>                  user     system      total        real
# >> Enumerable#to_a  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000126)
```

**Part - II**

```
require 'benchmark'

hsh = Hash[*1..1000]


Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report("Hash#to_a")    { hsh.to_a }
end
# >>                  user     system      total        real
# >> Hash#to_a     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000095)
```

Comment: Good answer, Arup.  You may wish to elaborate by explaining the connection between `Enumerable#to_a` and `Enumerable#entries`, and why Ruby would have both `Hash#to_a` and `Enumerable#to_a`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good point, I don't find any difference between `Enumerable#to_a` and `Enumerable#entries` ..

Comment: @CarySwoveland *why Ruby would have both `Hash#to_a` and `Enumerable#to_a`* _ I don't know..out of my subject :)

Comment: In MRI Ruby, `Enumerable#to_a` and `Enumerable#entries` are [implemented by exactly the same function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_353/enum.c#L2745-2746). I don’t know why Hash has its own `to_a`, my guess would be that it’s a speed / efficiency thing.

Comment: @Matt has echoed my understanding, that `Enumerable#to_a` and `Enumerable#entries` are synonyms (just as `Enumerable#reduce` and `Enumerable#inject` are), and that `Hash#to_a` has been provided because, for hashes, it is a more efficient implementation of that method than the more general `Enumerable#to_a`.  I'm guessing the latter is the case whenever an Enumerable method also appears in a class (such as `Array` or `Hash`) that includes `Enumerable`.  Can anyone tell me if my guess is correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland see my update.. I tried to show that `Hash#to_a` is faster than `Enumerable#to_a`..

Comment: Nice answer Arup.Performance apart,I guess above is also true for an `Array`.So I assume both can be used interchangeably