# Ruby accessing values of an object

Tags: ruby, class, variables

Say I have:

```
class Cell 
  def initialize(x_var, y_var)
    x = x_var
    y = y_var
  end
end
```

How would I be able to access the variables of the object cell?

```
cell1 = Cell.new(0, 0)

x = cell1.x
y = cell1.y
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things for you to learn:

1- Variable's scope

```
class Cell 
  def initialize(x_var, y_var)
    x = x_var
    y = y_var
  end

  def print_x
    puts x
  end
end

Cell.new(1,1).print_x
```

You get the following:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for #<Cell:0x007ff901d9f448>
```

In the code above, the variable `x` gets "lives" between `def initialize` and `end`. This is the scope of `x`. If you try to access `x` outside that scope, you'd get a `NameError` telling you it's not defined.

2- Now, if you want a variable that lives as long as the object does, you can use `instance variables`. Instance variables start with an `@` and live as long as the object does.

```
class Cell
  def initialize(x_var, y_var)
    @x = x_var
    @y = y_var
  end

  def x
    return @x
  end

  def x=(val)
    @x = val
  end

  def y
    return @y
  end

  def y=(val)
    @y = val
  end
end

c = Cell.new(1,2)
puts c.x
```

Gives the following:

```
1
=> nil
```

3- You had to write too much code in my example above to achieve very little. This is where @aruprakshit's `attr_reader` comes handy:

`attr_reader :x` generates the method:

```
def x
  return @x
end
```

4- If you want to read and write to `@x`, i.e., generate both the `x` and `x=` methods, `attr_accessor` does that for you:

```
class Cell
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(x_var, y_var)
    @x = x_var
    @y = y_var
  end
end

c = Cell.new(1,2)
puts c.x
c.x = 3
puts c.x
```

Gives the following:

```
1
=> nil
=> 3
3
=> nil
```

Comment: Just write `return @x` as `@x` only, no need here *return* keyword.

Comment: Yup... I know `return` is optional but for the sake of clarity in this basic example, I use it :-)

Comment: Have you already seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444202/difference-between-entries-and-to-a-in-ruby/20444223#20444223) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810588/how-to-track-the-execution-process-of-ruby-program/21810792#21810792) ?

Answer (score 2):

> How would I be able to access the variables of the object cell?

You need to look into [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) for this purpose.

```
class Cell 
  attr_reader :x,:y
  def initialize(x_var, y_var)
    @x = x_var
    @y = y_var
  end
end
cell1 = Cell.new(0, 0)

cell1.x # => 0
cell1.y # => 0
```

Read this [`Why use Ruby's attr_accessor, attr_reader and attr_writer?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046831/why-use-rubys-attr-accessor-attr-reader-and-attr-writer) to know about **attr_reader**.

Comment: Your example does not work. You must use `attr_accessor` or the `@`-variables.

Comment: @knut OP is using `x = cell1.x`, which is simply is saying he needs `getter`, not `setter`. See the question - *How would I be able to access the variables of the object cell?*.

Comment: @knut This solution works for me on ruby version 1.9.3. What version did you test this on?

Comment: @Matt there were edits after my answer - now it works.